# How to fix the floating point error in python

Tags: python, floating-point

I have been recently trying to make a calculator in python and added floating points in it
but unfortunately it gives me for this simple code

```
print(0.1 + 0.2)
```

> ***out put***

```
0.30000004
```

I have searched  a lot for it in stackoverflow but I keep getting questions about why it happened and not how to fix it.
Edit:
a lot of people have been recently giving me private feedbacks about  this already exists I appreciate that to improve stackoverflow but there are no questions most of them are explanations about why it is happening and not how to fix it. some of the feedbacks have got even questions that are not python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: Is `0.30000004` the actual output? If so, there's something very wrong. I'd expect something closer to `0.30000000000000004`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try any of the follow methods which is conventional for you

```
#for two decimal places use 2f, for 3 use 3f
val = 0.1 + 0.2
print(f"val = {val:.2f}")

#output | val = 0.30

#or else 
print(round(val,2))

#output | val = 0.30
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `decimal` built-in module with strings and make your own methods:

```
from decimal import Decimal
def exact_add(*nbs):
    return float(sum([Decimal(str(nb)) for nb in nbs]))

exact_add(0.1, 0.2)
# > 0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the recommended way to resolve this is to determine a number of decimal places you want to consider and round to that using the built-in `round` function. Say you want to use 5 decimal places, you could do:

```py
ans = 0.1 + 0.2
print(ans)    # 0.30000004
round(ans,5)
print(ans)    # 0.3
```

Note that round also gets rid of extra zeroes in the end. If you round `0.333333333333` to 5 decimals it will return `0.33333`, but rounding `0.30000000004` returns `0.3`.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with python, but with the way floating point values are represented on your machine. The way floating point works is the same for all languages, and it can potentially introduce rounding errors. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) shows you exactly why you get this error.

Just reduce the number of visible digits and you'll be fine. Just now that all computers and calculators have limited space for numbers, and all of them are prone to rounding errors.

Comment: You have not explained how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
a = 0.1 + 0.2
a = round(a, 2)
print(a)
Output: 0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

use round() syntax to get rid of excessive number of zeros.
'''

```
a = 0.1
b = 0.2
c = a + b 
answer = round(c,3)   # here 3 represents the number of digits you want to round
print(answer)
```

'''
and incase you want more clarification on round() syntax just visit this link once: https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/python-round